# Ultrasonic vibrations to clean solar cells?

Tags: mars, the-moon, solar-power, dust, sound

Could ultrasonic vibrations propagated into the solar cells be used to dislodge dust in environments like the surface of Mars or the moon?

Obviously the waves would need to be induced in the substrate other than through the air.

As an example; on earth we use ultrasonic cleaners to clean electronics all the time.

Comment: I would suspect the end effect of that would be cracking the solar cells.

Comment: Different questions, but related: [Brushing clean a Mars lander's solar panels](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32445/12102) and [Do solar panels on satellites gather dust and need cleaning?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5329/12102) and [Dust on Ingenuity solar panel](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51966/12102) and [Fast spinning solar cells to clear Martian dust possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35589/12102) and [Could dusters be installed on solar panels on a mars lander?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32300/12102)

Comment: and [Is InSight capable of cleaning itself?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32380/12102)

Comment: Possibly it could be used, but a vibrating system is yet another mechanical movement system imposing mechanical force on itself and the solar panel, even if just a piezoelectrical pulser. Similar (or greater) benefits can be found from electrodynamic cleaning systems, which are completely solid-state thus much less wear. In effect, induced static charges on the surface that cause the dust to hop, eventually hopping off the panel completely.

Comment: Somewhere in the history of photocopy machines there were surfaces with embedded wires that were driven like a motor, to push toner along the surface before it reached the drum, for uniform coating. It was not a mechanical vibration but it was an interesting way to move particles along to the edges of the surface. But right now I can't find any links to a description. I'm sure there are many old patents but I'm not up to a patent search.

Comment: @Tristan silicon *can be* really tough stuff, especially high grade/low defect single silicon. It's hard to believe but ultrathin single crystal silicon wafers are super flexible as long as there are no scratches (at which point they will instantly cleave) [1](https://www.virginiasemi.com/?cont_uid=18), [2](http://www.electron-mec.com/products/silicon-wafers/) If special panels were made from single crystal silicon and packaged properly they could be quite tough. However if there's any III-V in there that's *really really brittle* as it's full of defects due to very different ways of growth.

Comment: [3](https://www.topnewscorner.com/segmentation-of-thin-wafer-market-2019-by-type-application-regions/)

Comment: @Tristan I've just asked [Are the original ISS solar panels single or polycrystalline silicon? What about the new ROSA roll-out arrays?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55251/12102) and linked to your earlier answer.

Comment: @Alonda Are you referring to [dust reduction systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_reduction_system), as used in digital cameras, rather than the usual meaning of ultrasonic cleaner which involves immersing the item to be cleaned in a liquid?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.
Ultrasonic cleaners for electronics work by **immersing the dirty item in a bath** that both transmits vibrations to the item and collects the dirt that's been shaken off.  Vibrating a solar panel directly, you'd also have to invert or greatly tilt the panel to make the dirt fall off.  Even so, the dust might stay stuck on, due to static electricity.  That's another problem that a bath solves.